# Is it possible to pass an object parameter as an id in the find view by id

Tags: java, findviewbyid

Here is how I would naturally do this, are there any other possible ways that work?

```
public void error_checker(String Text_ID, int id,int id_2,String greater_num){
    if (id>id_2){


        TextView TextView = findViewById(R.id.Text_ID);

        TextView.setText(Integer.parseInt("You Answer Can't be Greater Than"+(greater_num));
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? And why do you write TextView TextView? It should throw error.

Comment: View IDs are `int`s, not `String`s.

Comment: @Michael how when for example this ID is android:id="@+id/age_enter_input"  ?

Comment: Because the resource compiler parses those ID strings in your XML files and generates a bunch of integer constants in an `R` class, which you then can pass to `findViewById`.

Comment: @Michael Right but you use a string to call the ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
  TextView textView = findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier(Text_ID, "id", getPackageName()););
```

Where Text_ID is the ID of your view (without the `R.id.` prefix)

Comment: Thanks, could you explain what getResources().getIdentifier and getPackageName() do ?